# Get list of all documents related to an account

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm working on an app to download all notes and documents related to an account in Sugar CRM. I'm building it as a C# console application, using the web service API as a web reference in my solution.

I think I have figured out the notes part but I can't figure out the documents part. Can anyone show me how to get a list of all documents per account using the web service API calls?

I am assuming that I should use get_relationships() to get documents, but how do I get the accounts module id? I don't have access to the database.

(My client is using sugar crm version 6.7.1 corporate)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, that you should use the API get_relationships. See the example to follow.

```
<?php
$get_relationships_parameters = array(
         'session'=>$session_id,

         //The name of the module from which to retrieve records.
         'module_name' => 'Accounts',

         //The ID of the specified module bean.
         'module_id' => '13111fcd-1884-2a71-0b37-50b7d0f188f6',

         //The relationship name of the linked field from which to return records.
         'link_field_name' => 'documents',

         //The portion of the WHERE clause from the SQL statement used to find the related items.
         'related_module_query' => '',

         //The related fields to be returned.
         'related_fields' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
         ),

         //For every related bean returned, specify link field names to field information.
         'related_module_link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
         ),

         //To exclude deleted records
         'deleted'=> '0',

         //order by
         'order_by' => '',

         //offset
         'offset' => 0,

         //limit
         'limit' => 5,
    );

$get_relationships_result = call("get_relationships", $get_relationships_parameters, $url);
?>
```

and you see result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entry_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 8b4c0450-1922-498f-4601-52272fa6e494
                    [module_name] => Documents
                    [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => id
                                    [value] => 8b4c0450-1922-498f-4601-52272fa6e494
                                )

                            [name] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => name
                                    [value] => WebProxyService_A.png
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [relationship_list] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

at url https://gist.github.com/amusarra/6436845 you will find the complete example. To get the account Id should use the API or get_entry get_entries.

I hope I have been of help.
Antonio